SQLAlchemy scalars and intersect anomaly
The SQLAlchemy manual says* that the Session.scalars() method returns ORM objects.
*Selecting ORM Entries
The following code shows two examples one of which returns an ORM object but the other does not. The first uses a select statement which selects a single ORM object. The second example does not return an ORM object. It is identical except for the introduction of SQLAlchemy’s intersect() function. It is only returning the first column of the desired object.
Although it is possible to select the primary keys of records and then carry out a second select for ORM objects that seems like a kludge. Is there a more elegant solution?
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, intersect
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase, Session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "movie"

    title: Mapped[str]
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}("
            f"title={self.title!r}, "
            f"id={self.id!r})"
        )


engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
with Session(engine) as session:
    movie_1 = Movie(title="Great Movie 1")
    movie_2 = Movie(title="Great Movie 2")
    session.add_all((movie_1, movie_2))

    statement = select(Movie).where(Movie.title == "Great Movie 1")
    print("\n", statement)
    result = session.scalars(statement).all()
    print(f"{result=}")

    stmt_isec = intersect(statement)
    # In case you're wondering, the next line has the same effect as 
    # the unary intersect.
    # stmt_isec = intersect(*[statement, statement])
    print("\n", stmt_isec)
    result = session.scalars(stmt_isec).all()
    print(f"{result=}")

Output:
SELECT movie.title, movie.id 
FROM movie 
WHERE movie.title = :title_1
result=[Movie(title='Great Movie 1', id=1)]

SELECT movie.title, movie.id 
FROM movie 
WHERE movie.title = :title_1 INTERSECT SELECT movie.title, movie.id 
FROM movie 
WHERE movie.title = :title_1
result=['Great Movie 1']

Use Case
The value of SQLAlchemy’s intersect function lies in its support of Python’s match statement. I’ve illustrated that in the ‘Naïve movie_bag’ example below. It’s only half the story, though. The match statement allows powerful search functions supported by generic data bags. The encapsulation of data into bags simplifies program design and GUI layouts. That is shown in the ‘Sophisticated movie_bag’ which follows.
(The MovieInt class turns an argument of '1939-1945' into an iterator which will return [1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945])
# Naïve movie_bag
movie_bag = {
    "year": 1943,
    "star": "Humphrey Bogart",
}
statements = []
for column, criteria in movie_bag.items():
    match column:
        case "year":
            statements.append(select(Movie).where(Movie.year == criteria))
        case "director":
            statements.append(select(Movie).where(Movie.director == criteria))
        case "star":
            statements.append(select(Movie).where(Movie.star == criteria))
intersect(*statements)

# Sophisticated movie_bag
movie_bag = {
    "year": MovieInt("1939-1945"),
    "stars": ["Humphrey", "Bergman"],
}
statements = []
for column, criteria in movie_bag.items():
    match column:
        case "year":
            statements.append(
                select(Movie).where(Movie.yearMovie.year.in_(list(criteria)))
            )
        case "director":
            for director in criteria:
                statements.append(
                    (
                        select(Movie)
                        .select_from(Movie)
                        .join(Movie.directors)
                        .where(Person.name.like(f"%{director}%"))
                    )
                )
        case "star":
            for star in criteria:
                statements.append(
                    (
                        select(Movie)
                        .select_from(Movie)
                        .join(Movie.stars)
                        .where(Person.name.like(f"%{star}%"))
                    )
                )
intersect(*statements)


Use from_statement like this to get ORM objects:
statement = select(Movie).where(Movie.title == "Great Movie 1")
stmt_isec = intersect(statement, statement)
session.scalars(select(Movie).from_statement(stmt_isec)).all()

Docs: selecting-entities-from-unions-and-other-set-operations

I honestly didn't know INTERSECT exists and reading about it I'm not sure when I would use it but it doesn't seem to apply to a single SELECT and sqlalchemy just runs a normal SELECT in that case.  So I tested it with the two redundant selects.

Thank you. I’ve added an explanation of the use case to the OQ.
